# Not sure how to finish proof regarding Im$(\varphi)$ for some homomorphism $\varphi\,:\,G\rightarrow H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

**My attempt so far:**

Im($\varphi$) has an element of order $n$ $\Rightarrow$ $j^n = e'$, for some $j\in$Im$(\varphi)$ $\Rightarrow$ $j\in G'$, and $j=\varphi (x)$ for some $x\in G$. Then $\varphi (x) ^n =e' \Rightarrow \varphi(x^n)=e' \Rightarrow x^n \in ker(\varphi)$.

I'm not sure how to get $x^n = e$. Could someone help me finish this, using what I have done so far?

Comment: Thank you Anurag. That's quite clever and helpful.

Comment: If you submit that as an answer I will verify it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\varphi(x)=j$, and $x$ has order $m$, and $j$ has order $n$, as you wrote. Then
$$
e'=\varphi(e)=\varphi(x^m)=\varphi(x)^m=j^m.
$$
This means $n$ divides $m$, so $m=nk$ for some $k$. Can you now adjust to get a power of $x$ with order $n$?

> Then the order of $x^k$ is $m/\gcd(m,k)=m/k=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ has order $k<n$, then $x^k=e \implies (\varphi(x))^k=e'$. Then it defies the minimality of $n$ as the order of $\varphi(x)$. This shows that $|x| \geq n$.

From $\phi(x)^k=e'$ we also get $n | k$ (since $n$ is the oder of $\varphi(x)$). Now use the minimality of $k$ (as order of $x$) to claim it being equal to $n$.